# TryParse Nullable types generically

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, generics, type-conversion

I have written overloaded static `TryParse` methods for the following `Nullable` types: `int?`, `short?`, `long?`, `double?`, `DateTime?`, `decimal?`, `float?`, `bool?`, `byte?` and `char?`.  Below is some of the implementation:

```
protected static bool TryParse(string input, out int? value)
{
    int outValue;
    bool result = Int32.TryParse(input, out outValue);
    value = outValue;
    return result;
}

protected static bool TryParse(string input, out short? value)
{
    short outValue;
    bool result = Int16.TryParse(input, out outValue);
    value = outValue;
    return result;
}

protected static bool TryParse(string input, out long? value)
{
    long outValue;
    bool result = Int64.TryParse(input, out outValue);
    value = outValue;
    return result;
}
```

The logic is the same in every method except that they use different types.  Would it not be possible to use generics so that I don't need to have so much redundant code?  The signature would look like this:

```
bool TryParse<T>(string input, out T value);
```

Thanks

Comment: One reason a generic method for this is not suitable is not all `struct`s have `TryParse` methods, but you can't use a generic constraint to only allow compatible types at compile time.

Comment: By the way, you're missing the `?` after the second `T` in your proposed method signature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Would it not be possible to use generics so that I don't need to have so much redundant code?

You could do it with reflection, but that would be relatively slow. Otherwise, you *could* create a map from type to "method to use for that type" but it would be pretty ugly. Aside from anything else, it would never be *truly* generic - it would only work for types that provided a `TryParse` method of the right signature, which couldn't be known at compile-time.

I would personally consider changing the signature and behaviour, by the way. Currently even though the type of `value` is nullable, it will never have the null value at the end of the method, even if you return `false`. Why not make the return value the result of the parsing operation, returning `null` on failure?

```
protected static long? TryParseInt64(string input)
{
    long outValue;
    return Int64.TryParse(input, out outValue) ? (long?) outValue : null;
}
```

Comment: In that case, I'll stay away from generics.  Regarding your suggestion, I need the signature to be in the form of `bool TryParse(string input, out object value)` so to be consistent with .NET's `TryParse` methods.

Comment: @davenewza: Then you should *at least* change the behaviour so that `value` is `null` if `result` is `false`, to be consistent with the other `TryParse` methods: the `out` parameter should always have the default value of the type (which is `null` for nullable types) when it returns `false`.

Comment: Ah, absolutely.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Your method is wrong. It is supposed to parse a _Nullable_ `Int64`, so passing the `"null"` string is supposed to be success, and in this case `"null"` and `"foobar"` would yield the same result.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM, the method you're proposing functions differently to the one in the question. I think your comment should be aimed at the person who wrote the question; it's their requirements, not Jon's.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the following generic extension method,

```
public static Nullable<TSource> TryParse<TSource>(this string input) where TSource : struct
{
    try
    {
        var result = Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(TSource));
        if (result != null)
        {
            return (TSource)result;
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The following call will return the nullable parsed type.

```
string s = "510";
int? test = s.TryParse<int>();
//TryParse Returns 510 and stored in variable test.

string s = "TestInt";
int? test = s.TryParse<int>();
//TryParse Returns null and stored in variable test.
```

Answer (score 4):

As an aside, you could refactor your code:

```
public static bool TryParse(string input, out int? value)
{
    return TryParse(input, Int32.TryParse, out value);
}

protected static bool TryParse(string input, out short? value)
{
    return TryParse(input, Int16.TryParse, out value);
}

protected static bool TryParse(string input, out long? value)
{
    return TryParse(input, Int64.TryParse, out value);
}

private static bool TryParse<T>(string input, TryParseFunc<T> tryParse, out T? value)
    where T : struct
{
    T outValue;
    bool result = tryParse(input, out outValue);
    value = outValue;
    return result;
}

private delegate bool TryParseFunc<T>(string input, out T value);
```

Comment: I like it. That's neat. It also makes the change I was suggesting very simple - you just use `value = result ? outValue : (T?) null` on the third line of the implementation part.

Comment: This is great.  Thanks!  Will also include the `null` default value as Jon suggested.

Comment: There should be a badge for posting an answer that @JonSkeet himself approves in a comment.