# cannot convert from 'string' to 'int?'8

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have to bind gridview by selecting the drop down list. While using the given below code generate one error. The error is :" cannot convert from 'string' to int". How can I solve this issue. Please Help me.

Code:

```
protected void ddlVersionNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_ShadingAnalysisTableAdapter adp1;
        adp1 = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_ShadingAnalysisTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = adp1.GetGridData(ddlSiteID.SelectedValue, ddlVersionNo.SelectedValue); //error is shown here
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT Site_ID, version_number,A,B FROM tbl_ShadingAnalysis WHERE Site_ID=@Site_ID AND version_number=@version_number
```

Data Base:

[image]

Comment: On which line exactly? What is your `GetGridData` method do?

Comment: can you at least give us a hint which line / etc reports this? I'm *assuming* that it is the `GetGridData`; so: what is the signature of that method? `DropDownList.SelectedValue` is `string`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only *guess* from the image that `GetGridData` has the signature:

```
DataTable GetGridData(string siteId, int versionNumber)
```

in which case, since `DropDownList.SelectedValue` is `string`, you'll need to parse:

```
DataTable dt = adp1.GetGridData(
    ddlSiteID.SelectedValue, int.Parse(ddlVersionNo.SelectedValue));
```

Comment: `VerionNumber` is nullable, so the second parameter is a `int?`(the title also suggests it).

Comment: +1 That seems to be the logical deduction from the information provided

Comment: @TimSchmelter the user posted SQL with a `version_number=@version_number` - so either the parameter is non-nullable, or broken ;p

Comment: @ Marc Gravell user seems to be trying to convert string to int?, as I can understand from the question, so need to do something like  what Jon suggests in following link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851527/tryparse-nullable-types-generically

Comment: @MarcGravell:  maybe he just wants to find records with a given `version_number` and it's not possible that `null` is passed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your Site_ID as an "int" or make a new Primary Key.

```
 SELECT Site_ID, version_number,A,B FROM tbl_ShadingAnalysis WHERE Site_ID=@Site_ID AND version_number=@version_number
```

Data Base needs to have a Primary Key that is an Integer!